# VS code how to show unused variables as red

Tags: visual-studio-code

My editor settings have graying out enabled for unused imports and variables: `"editor.showUnused": true`

But how can I change it so that instead of being grayed out, the line has a red background?

This is a Javascript file.

[image: unused variable import in vscode]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, It seems like this option was removed from version 1.25.

Please refer to: [Improve color name `editorUnnecessary.foreground`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/51152)

Comment: Hi, could you help? I've tried all the fixes here, and none work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118036/vscode-is-not-graying-out-unused-variables

Answer (score 47):

While messing around in the Visual Studio Code (v1.38.0) settings.json for a colorblind coworker, I found success with this setting:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#dd7aab"
},
```

The ^ setting does not exactly solve your desire for a red background, but it does provide an alternative that will help accentuate the unused item. This is what it looks like for us:

[image]

[image]

FYI: I had failures while playing around with the following settings:

```
editorUnnecessary.foreground
editorUnnecessaryCode.foreground

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorUnnecessary.foreground": "#dd7aab"
}

"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
  "editorUnnecessaryCode.foreground": "#dd7aab"
}
```

The VSCode team needs to finalize the plan and documentation for the theming of the unused (unnecessary) code.

Comment: I have search extensively, and as of 2019-11-27 this is still the only possible solution.

Comment: The large part of an IDE is the static analysis tools that indicate things like unused vars. Why did they think it was a good idea to remove this?? Its like how vcpkg doesn't have a way to pull specific library versions. Is that not the point of a package manager??

Comment: @AnthonyO vs code is not an IDE. It is a text editor with plugins. I keep trying to tell this to my co-workers who refuse to move to a fully functioning IDE, but they won't do it.

Comment: @rocksNwaves You may be right but it passes the duck test for me

Answer (score 11):

**Step 1:** Open `Settings` Page.

- Click on `File`. It will open file menu.
- Click/Hover on `Preferences`(In MacOS, `Preferences` option is moved under `Code` tab).  It will open Preferences menu.
- Click on `Settings` option. It will open the settings page.

**Step 2:** Open `settings.json`.

- On settings page, Click on `Appearance` tab (In latest VS Code, `Appearance` tab is moved under `Workbench` tab). It will show `Appearance` options.
- Inside that check for `Color Customizations` option. It would have link `Edit in settings.json`. Click on that link.
- It will open `settings.json`

**Step 3:** Update the setting.

- Use `editorUnnecessaryCode.border` to update border color of Unnecessary Code.

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
   "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#ff0000"
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use following settings in file settings.json. 
Font color and background color cannot be changed, only opacity can be changed. 
If the last 2 digits are FF, it means that Opacity is set to 1 which means completely opaque element. 
It doesn't matter what are the 1st 6 digits, only the last 2 digits matters. 
There's some default opacity which is overridden by this setting. 
Example:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.opacity": "#000000FF"
}
```

In addition, we can add colored underlying. 
Example:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#FF0000"
}
```

Note: to activate previous settings, you need to use:

```
{
    "editor.showUnused": true
}
```