# VScode is not graying out unused variables

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, settings

I've found many answers on here, however none of them work.

[VS code how to show unused variables as red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53517219/vs-code-how-to-show-unused-variables-as-red)

[VS code doesn't gray out unused variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55477660/vs-code-doesnt-gray-out-unused-variables)

[VSCode - gray out unused imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258541/vscode-gray-out-unused-imports)

As we can see here, `Component` is not grayed out. Screenshot for color example

[image]
^ screenshot to show the highlighting issue

**Code block:** (this line import { Component } from 'react', should be grayed out, also const happy should be grayed out.

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import './search-box.styles.css'

const happy = ''

const SearchBox = ({ className, placeholder, onChangeHandler }) => {
  return (
    <input
      className={`search-box ${className}`}
      type='search'
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={onChangeHandler}
    />
  )
}

export default SearchBox
```

**All the settings I've tried:**

```
"javascript.validate.enable": true,
"javascript.showUnused.enabled": true,
"typescript.showUnused.enabled": true,
"editor.showUnused": true,
```

I observe the same behavior when I delete all my user settings (which resets them to the default).

When I run VS Code with extensions disabled, I observe the same behavior.

VS Code version

```
Version: 1.82.2 (Universal)
Commit: abd2f3db4bdb28f9e95536dfa84d8479f1eb312d
Date: 2023-09-14T05:59:47.790Z
Electron: 25.8.1
ElectronBuildId: 23779380
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 22.6.0
```

VS Code Extensions

```
Babel ES6/ES7
Better Comments
colorize
crates
Docker
DotENV
Emmet commands and keybindings
ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets
Even Better TOML
GitHub Theme
GitLens
GraphQL
IntelliCode
IntelliCode API Usage Examples
Live Server
Markdown All in One
Material Icon Theme
Mithril Emmet
One Dark Pro
Path Autocomplete
Prettier - Code formatter
rust-analyzer
Snazzy Operator
Spirted Away Color Theme
Stylelint
Tailwind CSS intelliSense
vsode-icons
vscode-styled-components
```

Comment: if the theme does not support semantic highlighting.....

Comment: @rioV8 just tried Monokai and Github Dark, same issues... what theme do you use?

Comment: try with the default themes Light+ and Dark+, these themes have all the features

Comment: Just did, same issue with Light+ @rioV8

Comment: Is it greyed out in StackBlitz? I've created an exmpale where `Component` is greyed out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gc8tz9?file=src%2FApp.tsx Is it greyed out in a clean VSCode configuration without all these settings and custumizations. Do you have additional extensions? It looks like you've copied these settings from somewhere? Where did you copy it from? Can you ask the author?

Comment: I'll share my extensions in the question above I think maybe one of those may be messing with me. The settings I've gotten from all over, over the last couple years.

With the settings reset to nothing or just with `"editor.showUnused": true,` I still have unused var coloring issue.

Comment: @ThomasSablik and yes it's working in StackBlitz, so maybe something with my editor

Comment: @starball added! And yes after running that Extensions disabled command the Component is still not grayed out.

Comment: Please give us a [mre]- minimal example code that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @starball posted the component example, also I've reinstalled VScode, disabled all my extensions and still have this problem! lol... Still digging in

Comment: I think for global variables it's just like that because for non-module code, it can't be known where the global variable might be used. For the export issue, I can't reproduce the issue with a simple setup. Does your project folder have a tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json?

Comment: @ThomasSablik was able to reproduce it here in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-w63j8j?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: as I said, I think it's just like that for global variables. If you wrap that code in your stackblitz into a function, then the variables are treated as unused variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255320/discussion-between-leon-gaban-and-starball).

Comment: [/help/duplicates](/help/duplicates)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**Found the answer here:**

[VisualStudioCode editor.showUnused true not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60225214/visualstudiocode-editor-showunused-true-not-working)

Had to completely uninstall VScode and run some extra rm -rf commands
https://jimkang.medium.com/complete-uninstall-remove-vscode-mac-5e48bef3bdec

Step 1

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code
// add sudo if you needed to
// if you're using insider*
sudo rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code\ -\ Insiders/
```

Step 2

```
rm -rf $HOME/.vscode
// add sudo if you needed to
// if you're using insider*
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.vscode-insiders/
```

Comment: Also, all of a sudden my emment tab works again too!